Me pueden apoyar con esta for con consulta dinamica en PL/SQL
Necesito hacer hacer un select con 2 condiciones y cada condición tiene una variable dinamica, la primera in_tb_destino trae el nombre de la tabla y la segunda inner_keys_sep trae una cadena de varios valores como esto inner_keys_sep: 'mes_cumpleaños', 'dia_cumpleaños', 'msisdn', 'id_suscriptor', 'id_cliente', 'fecha_activacion', 'ciudad', 'primer_nombre_contacto'.
    v_upd_json :='';
    for conf in (SELECT DISTINCT columna_sabana, tipo, campos_llave FROM URTPSTG.conf_sabana_cte WHERE TABLA_DESTINO = in_tb_destino AND columna_json IN (inner_keys_sep))
    loop
      v_col_sabana:=conf.columna_sabana;   
      -- Iterar sobre las claves internas y obtener sus valores
      v_json :='';
      v_json2 :='';


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y cual es el problema?
